# Asp.net Linq query throwing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

**Error details:**
Unable to create a constant value of type '`Huntable.Data.MasterEmployee`'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

```
IList<MasterEmployee> masterEmployees = sizeIds
    .Select(followerId => MasterDataManager.AllEmployees
    .Single(x => x.Id == followerId)).ToList(); 
rspdata.DataSource = CompanyManager.GetCompanyJobs(masterEmployees); 

IList<Company> companies = new List<Company>();
IQueryable<IGrouping<string, Job>> job = from c in context.Jobs
    group c by c.CompanyName;
IList<string> comapnyname= (
    from gro in job 
    from masterEmployee in sizeids 
    where gro.Count() >= masterEmployee.Min 
       && gro.Count() <= masterEmployee.Max select gro.Key).ToList();
var companiesList = companies.ToList();
```

Company name line is getting the following exception.

Comment: `from masterEmployee in sizeids` where do sizeids come from ?

Comment: IList<MasterEmployee> masterEmployees = sizeIds.Select(followerId => MasterDataManager.AllEmployees.Single(x => x.Id == followerId)).ToList();
            rspdata.DataSource = CompanyManager.GetCompanyJobs(masterEmployees);

Comment: You are probably joining in memory objects and linq2sql query expression and linq is not able to translate it to sql. Please update your question with more code (we need to know what kind of objects `masterEmployee`, `sizeids`... Maybe you should explain is little bit what are you trying to acomplish (Please update your question - code inside a comment is absolutely non-readable).

Comment: Added the code in your comment + split long lines. We still don't know what `sizeIds` is. For the best response please pay attention to readability and be quick to anwer comments. It's for your own benefit.